# Regex newline selecting

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

My code: 
`Regex("([A-Za-z0-9]{5})=([^\n]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);`

Sample text:

`ab94c=some text here
a6u4c=sample text here
sample text continues. it contains a newline character.
gh94c=some more text here`

This is what I get: https://regex101.com/r/cN6gJ5/1

This is what I want: [image: what I want]

Every text has an id. I want to capture the id and every character until the next id. I want to create an array like this:

array[ab94c] = some text here

array[a6u4c] = sample text here

sample text continues. it contains a newline character.

array[gh94c] = some more text here

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: Have you checked the regex101 link I've given? It doesn't capture second line of the string.

Comment: Indeed I did, I does find three matches, as expected!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QMYV0rC.jpg This is what I want

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems." (Fredrik Lundh, 1998)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
@"(?s)(?:^|\n)([A-Za-z0-9]{5})=(.*?)(?=\n[A-Za-z0-9]{5}=|$)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cN6gJ5/2)

- If you use DOTALL modifier `(?s)` in the regex, `^` matches only the start of very first line.
- So this `(?:^|\n)` matches the start of very first line or the new line character,
- which exists before `([A-Za-z0-9]{5})=` 5 alphanumeric chars and an `=` symbol. And this captures that alphanum chars.
- Now `(.*?)` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more chars until

  1. `\n[A-Za-z0-9]{5}=` a newline followed by 5 alphanum chars plus an `=` sign is reached.  OR
  2. `$` of the line is reached. Here `$` matches the end of the last line only since we are using DOTALL modifier.

Comment: How you get the screen-shot of expected output?

Comment: with some MS Paint skills